# Python 3: How can I match 2 sound wave signals

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing

Python 3: How can I match 2 sound wave signals, one signal is recorded and saved another is captured on the go, Below are the signals and their freq transform, I need a value in terms of % how much they match,

Comment: Could take the difference of the fourier transform histograms (in frequency domain) and sum the resulting histogram using some sort of metric.

Answer (score 0):

You could cross correlate the live stream with the recorded signal.  If they match perfectly, the cross correlation would be 1 (100%).

Comment: that was one of the first things I tried, But the problem is waves are not 100% same, they are audio(speech) waves in array form,  So can be delayed or have some random differences. Was looking for light-weight code to match them. tried the Fourier transform matching later